# Python parse dictionary

Tags: python, gcloud

I have this,

```
from gcloud import datastore

dataset = datastore.Client(dataset_id='wifi-XXX')
entity = datastore.Entity(key=dataset.key('TokenEntity'))
query = dataset.query(kind='TokenEntity')
query.add_filter('name', '>', '')
for i in query.fetch():
    print i
```

when I used it the result is:

```
   <Entity[{'kind': u'TokenEntity', 'name': u'z7jm0uRV'}] {u'createdOn': datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 4, 9, 0, 51, 830000, tzinfo=<UTC>), u'used': False, u'createdBy': 
    u'jiri.m@veolia.com', u'ssid': u'XXX-Public', u'usedOn': None}>

<Entity[{'kind': u'TokenEntity', 'name': u'z8bL1sVV'}] {u'createdOn': datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 4, 9, 2, 20, 240000, tzinfo=<UTC>), u'used': False, u'createdBy': 
    u'jiri.s@xxx.com', u'ssid': u'XXX-Public', u'usedOn': None}>

<Entity[{'kind': u'TokenEntity', 'name': u'zKVzBvDV'}] {u'createdOn': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 22, 17, 1, 54, 817000, tzinfo=<UTC>), u'used': False, u'createdBy' : u'jaromir.s@vvv.com', u'ssid': u'XXX-Public', u'usedOn': None}>


I can use:

>>> i['used']
False

>>> i['createdBy']
u'jaromir.s@xxx.com'
>>> i['ssid']
u'XXX-Public'
>>>
```

But it's impossible get 'name'

> > > i['name']
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "", line 1, in 
> > >           KeyError: 'name'

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with gcloud platform, but that's what I see:

*The Key methods kind() and id() recover the entity's kind and identifier from the key:*

So, just try:

```
i.kind()
i.id()
i.name()
```